# Exception when running in docker: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "hamzabelmellouki"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am pretty new to docker. I have a spring-boot application that connects to postgres database (running in a container). I want to dockerize my spring-boot application and be able to connect it to the postgres database container.

What works:

- Running the application without using docker works just fine: `java -jar product-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

What doesn't work:

- Dockerizing and Running the application with Docker gives me an exception.

Note that I am not using docker-compose here.
My app Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

### Steps I've taken to run the app:

1. Run and start up the postgres database in a container using these commands:

   `docker run --rm --name lil-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -v $HOME/srv/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres`

   `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`
2. I've built the app's image:

`docker build -t ensa/product-manager .`
This is the result from running the latest command:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  38.01MB
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:11
 ---> 612d4d483eee
Step 2/4 : ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
 ---> Running in 1b8674e959ca
Removing intermediate container 1b8674e959ca
 ---> d2c2b90680de
Step 3/4 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
 ---> 01295beecd1b
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
 ---> Running in 31230e7ff323
Removing intermediate container 31230e7ff323
 ---> c4487683e7b1
Successfully built c4487683e7b1
Successfully tagged ensa/product-manager:latest
```

3. Finally, I've created a running container using:

`docker run --net="host" -it ensa/product-manager`

The third step resulted in an exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "hamzabelmellouki"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:520) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar!/:42.2.8]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
        at com.ensa.productmanager.ProductManagerApplication.main(ProductManagerApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

I've spent the whole day debugging and reading threads about this error. But I couldn't find a clue. Any help will be much appreciated.

### UPDATE

I've run `docker inspect` on the Postgres container:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "426744f8c0a90b504c4d7c22242929f4b7f833e3ff4ddb9a112139d18ffd7c10",
        "Created": "2020-01-16T19:14:14.7290504Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "postgres"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 8057,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-01-16T19:14:15.5451891Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:e2d75d1c1264a777df31dcbd4fd452b238134eb27854c2a173fdbfaa47ce9b87",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/426744f8c0a90b504c4d7c22242929f4b7f833e3ff4ddb9a112139d18ffd7c10/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/426744f8c0a90b504c4d7c22242929f4b7f833e3ff4ddb9a112139d18ffd7c10/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/426744f8c0a90b504c4d7c22242929f4b7f833e3ff4ddb9a112139d18ffd7c10/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/426744f8c0a90b504c4d7c22242929f4b7f833e3ff4ddb9a112139d18ffd7c10/426744f8c0a90b504c4d7c22242929f4b7f833e3ff4ddb9a112139d18ffd7c10-json.log",
        "Name": "/lil-postgres",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/Users/hamzabelmellouki/srv/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": true,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/baabe07f985a61979a3752f7e3c43116b980c45682d27c660b2867a6af3da28b-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ac6700580b74ace6c2f4eb9c274ef405124afb8019948c51516b496ed62eae8d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/35c484f8059617661ae54f749d0b938e7d81bc2089dd81ef81952aed6079c30b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1649505946cf497fd95a5b7a118150a09315767464671f93459e3324f8e5ac42/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/69a4818765c800f405e11c7755e184e4fd0837b68b4664821cf9c80daa7b629b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/177d3596510c3fdb235ec84728b8b6baf23a406dca3e9a3bfb45e98b48fe2395/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/07d15f6f98f43ff88e6bdf9e361fadaaa46f83121278b5dbddac372cb95d99b8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5e10c2001ef13459900f124ae825c210e2e001b0aa2f8b5e1e7c8c5c27d9e403/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b1e7828ebe991a7401746f581fd640bca3ae74f3a9820fd15e0fb2c666a08754/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1b274467493537d29e25cce71acf9c3020d8a2e25080c75aa0fca10a5c05789/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/11141fed542b6c519ec7621e0c4f341d2b2822a7c2885980216a2ef27609ffe0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c3e4e9634bfe6a9e4b26f3d2d5751b2fa01aae0e8e1679a800accd94179d527d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e7da8a834521c827046a2dc64f6f39afa6fded7f1af3241c75c592756d3053d6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/91d22f9b7d3aa1fae5cabcfe245a18c7dc6ac372696c73be70b65f7c8b42f1f4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1a2021467ef42428eda11a9aef133e4b7ee9364266255abe5a0f2df4a9ff2584/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/baabe07f985a61979a3752f7e3c43116b980c45682d27c660b2867a6af3da28b/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/baabe07f985a61979a3752f7e3c43116b980c45682d27c660b2867a6af3da28b/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/baabe07f985a61979a3752f7e3c43116b980c45682d27c660b2867a6af3da28b/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/hamzabelmellouki/srv/postgres",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "426744f8c0a9",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "POSTGRES_USER=hamzabelmellouki",
                "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.11",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=11",
                "PG_VERSION=11.5-1.pgdg90+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "postgres"
            ],
            "Image": "postgres",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "2649b309ebde1f690927a1081497c9dc05dc249642b429f25d930243eb81e08f",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/2649b309ebde",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "f01f60128018d8634f26a0c683ee6865e20361548b3a49007804dc913bfc4292",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "045d48c0f1d22cb7c319d6e850f6e9985a08e6d08884a79e823dbd0ac6c8a1b9",
                    "EndpointID": "f01f60128018d8634f26a0c683ee6865e20361548b3a49007804dc913bfc4292",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure the postgres credentials you provided to your spring application are correct?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned when I run the app without docker (using ```java -jar app.jar``` or ```mvn spring-boot:run```). The spring app works just fine.

Comment: Where are you configuring the location and credentials of the database?  I don't see that mentioned anywhere in the `docker run` commands you've shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe,you can use **docker-compose** to defining and running multi-container docker applications(postgres+spring-boot) and you use a **YAML** file to configure your application's services.

So,You must create new volumes with different path to insert new data with new schema and configuration,because if you use volumes that already used before so you will find the problems like password authentication failed for user “hamzabelmellouki”
or the user(role) “hamzabelmellouki” does not existe or the database "database's name" does not existe because they have other user rhat created before .

```
#####docker-compose.yml#####
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: lil-postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: hamzabelmellouki
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: hamzabelmellouki
    networks:
      - product-net

  product:
    image: ensa/product-manager
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - product-net

networks:
  product-net:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

1. While running Postgres container, you have not provided any username , it should be something like:

   docker run --rm **--net="host"** --name lil-postgres -e **POSTGRES_USER=hamzabelmellouki** -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -v $HOME/srv/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres:9.6
2. by default Postgres container will run in **bridge network** (default docker network) and in your app, you've provided **--net="host"**
   So maybe due to that, they are not able to communicate.
   Provide the same network while running both

You can check it by below command

`docker inspect container_name` (or container_id)

Its nothing related, still, I've updated the docker image tag(Postgres:9.6), as it's always good to use a particular tag name, instead of default one (latest tag).

Comment: None of the suggested solutions works! I believe the app container couldn't communicate with the db container. I've tried many things to enable communication. Any other suggestions, please?

Comment: Concerning the second suggestion, it didn't work. Running ```docker run -it ensa/product-manager``` produces another exception: ```org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.```

Comment: `docker run -it ensa/product-manager` this is not enough, you need to run above command I mentioned.

remove  **--net="host"** from both docker command and try.

or enter  `docker network create test` first and then update network name from host to test in both docker commands

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried running them on the same host but it doesn't work: ```org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "hamzabelmellouki" does not exist```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing localhost by the ip adresse 172.17.0.2  in the application.properties spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/testdb